# How to interpret this logistic regression question?

Tags: probability, logistic, odds

This is from a DataCamp course. Try as I might, I can't seem to figure out how to break this down into explanations:

The fitted coefficient β^1 from the medical school logistic regression model is 5.45. The exponential of this is 233.73.

Donald's GPA is 2.9, and thus the model predicts that the probability of him getting into medical school is 3.26%. The odds of Donald getting into medical school are 0.0337, or—phrased in gambling terms—29.6:1. If Donald hacks the school's registrar and changes his GPA to 3.9, then which of the following statements is FALSE:

- His expected odds of getting into medical school improve to 7.8833(or about 9:8).
- His expected probability of getting into medical school improves to 88.7%.
- His expected log-odds of getting into medical school improve by 5.45.
- His expected probability of getting into medical school improves to 7.9%.

I am not asking for the right answer here, I am asking for some guide on the thought process and how to solve this question. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways the logistic regression model can be rewritten. Let $X$ denote the student's GPA.

The standard way the model is expressed is in terms of the log odds. We have

$$\text{log}\left(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\right)=\alpha+5.45X$$

and so a one unit increase in $X$ would increase the expected log odds by 5.45. Exponentiating both sides we get

$$\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}=\text{exp}(\alpha+5.45X)$$

and so we'd expect a one unit increase in $X$ to multiply the odds by $\text{exp}(5.45)\approx 233.73$

Finally it can be shown that

$$\pi=\frac{\text{exp}(\alpha+5.45X)}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+5.45X)}=\frac{\text{odds}}{1+\text{odds}}$$

so the predicted probability can be found after finding the predicted odds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation!